# Restart remote tomcat which is running in remote machine?

Tags: java, tomcat, batch-file, cmd

I have the tomcat up and running on remote machine.
Now i need to create a batch file to restart the tomcat. I am using windows.

```
Stop tomcat

start tomcat
```

How can i write  a batch file to restart it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There are scripts in the bin directory of tomcat that will start and stop it called starup.bat and shutdown.bat IIRC. You will have to ssh in to remotely run them.

Also, if you're running as a Windows Service, there are ways to remote manage those service, but my Windows is rusty. You'll need to google for that.

You'll need to write a batch file either to SSH in or to restart the service.

Comment: Thom, i just need to create a batch file. On double click it has to restart the tomcat.

Comment: @user755806 I don't understand your point. You need to use ssh or the remote windows service API to restart your service on a remote machine. You can place the calls to these in a batch file on your computer.

Comment: Could you please take me to any link to find out any example if you have plz?

Comment: @user755806 don't have one. Sorry.

Comment: @Thom: which port to use while SSHing?

Comment: @gaurav That depends on how it's configured on that server. I always use the default port.